# Highstock chart is not showing which points are selected

Tags: highcharts

I have just started exploring highcharts API. I am trying to create a highstock chart where I can select some points from the chart and edit/delete the values. However, even though I have got the selected points, I could not see them marked on the chart. The following code is working fine for highcharts, but not for highstock:

```
 var option = {                           
         chart: {
           renderTo: 'container',
           defaultSeriesType: 'line',
           width: 800,
           height:500,
           events: {
                    selection: function(event) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < this.series[0].data.length; i++) {
                            var point = this.series[0].data[i];
                            console.log("Point:",point.y,point.x);
                            if (point.x >= event.xAxis[0].min &&
                                point.x <= event.xAxis[0].max &&
                                point.y >= event.yAxis[0].min &&
                                point.y <= event.yAxis[0].max) {
                                    console.log("selecting");
                                    this.series[0].data[i].select(true,true);                                       
                                }                               
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                zoomType: 'xy'
              },

              title: {
                text: "Test",
                margin: 100,
                backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
              },


              rangeSelector: {
                    inputBoxStyle: {
                        right: '-280px'
                    },
                    //selected: 0
              },

              xAxis: {
                 type: 'datetime',
                 tickInterval: 14 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
                 tickWidth: 0,
                 gridLineWidth: 1,
                 labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 3,
                    y: -3 
             }
              },

              yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: yAxisTitle
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 3,
                    y: 16,
                    formatter: function() {
                       return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                      }
                },
                showFirstLabel: false
              }, { 
             linkedTo: 0,
             gridLineWidth: 0,
             opposite: true,
             title: {
                text: "Target Steps"
             },
             labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: 0,
                    y: 16,
                    formatter: function() {
                       return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                    }
             },
             showFirstLabel: false
              }],

             legend: {
                 align: 'left',
                 verticalAlign: 'top',
                 y: 20,
                 floating: true,
                 borderWidth: 0
              },

              tooltip: {
                 shared: true,
                 crosshairs: true
              },

              plotOptions: {
                 series: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    marker: {
                       enabled: true,
                    },
                    point: {
                       events: {
                       click: function() {
                          (this).select(true,true);
                          hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                            pageOrigin: {
                               x: this.pageX, 
                               y: this.pageY
                            },
                            headingText: ''+Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b %Y', this.x) +':<br/>',                                                                      
                            maincontentText:"Test",                                                                                                     
                            width: 400,
                            height:220


                         });
                      }
                   }
                },
                marker: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                 }
              },
              series: [{
                 name: seriesName[0],
                 lineWidth: 4,
                 marker: {
                    radius: 4
                 }
              },{
                 name: seriesName[1]
              }],

        };
        var series = {
              data: []
        };
        options.series[0].data = myArray[0];
        options.series[1].data = myArray[1];


        window.historic_chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
```

I would really appreciate if anyone helps me find out a solution to this problem and explains why the selected points are not marked on the highstock charts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are using sometimes dataGrouping, so you have empty series.data array. In that case use series groupedData to list points, see: http://jsfiddle.net/awGwn/2/

```
            events: {
                selection: function (event) {
                    console.log(this);
                    var points = this.series[0].data;
                    if(points.length  == 0 ) {
                         points = this.series[0].groupedData;   
                    }
                    for (var i in points) {
                        var point = points[i];
                        console.log("Point:", point.y, point.x);
                        if (point.x >= event.xAxis[0].min && point.x <= event.xAxis[0].max && point.y >= event.yAxis[0].min && point.y <= event.yAxis[0].max) {
                            console.log("selecting");
                            point.select(true, true);
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            },
            zoomType: 'xy'
```

If this won't help, recrate issue by upgrading my jsFiddle, please.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. I have recreated in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ua6dA/1/. I haven't changed much..just using line charts insted on column and candlestick.
Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. But still I've got the problem. Please have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/nkhdc/. Usually if I click on a point the marker changes its colour from a darkblue circle to white circle. But if I want to capture the click events, then it doesn't work. And I also want to change the colour of the markers when I drag the mouse to select multiple points.
Would you please check what the problem is?

Comment: Well....it's working now. It seems I messed up with the marker. Thanks for helping me solving this issue.